# Use different queues on a celery chain

Tags: python, celery

I'm trying to use different queues for each task in a chain. I'm using the code below, but the consumer gets all the messages from the incoming queue and put everything on the queue `saveRequestQueue`, but those messages are not processed further than that.

```
chain = (    
    tasks.save_request_task.s(transient_schema.dict()).set(queue="saveRequestQueue")
    | tasks.get_customer_summary_task.s().set(queue="getCustomerSummaryQueue")
    | tasks.save_analysis_task.s().set(queue="saveAnalysisQueue")
    | tasks.answer_to_credit_engine_task.s().set(queue="answerToCreditEngineTask")
)
chain()
```

I've tried to use the same queue on the `.set()` method and it worked like a charm. But I do need to have different queues for each task.

Any ideas for the reason all the messages get stuck on the first queue?

Answer (score 1):

I tested this snippet literally 15 min ago and it seems to work perfectly:

```
fetch_init_t = fetch_init_data.s(args).set(queue="updates")

fetch_next_t = get_next.s(next_request_args).set(queue="next")

tasks.append(chain(fetch_init_t, fetch_next_t).delay())
```

I use `celery==5.3.1` with `redis:alpine-latest` for both results and transport.